# How to change webadmin url path

Tags: neo4j

How to change webadmin url path?
The default one is localhost with port.
Can I change as localhost with additional path?

Answer (score 0):

There's no indication that you can have an additional port. To change the default port, open `conf/neo4j-server.properties`, change `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port`. This will change the port used for all REST communication, not just the web admin, so make sure to update any app that relies on the REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I understand I can change the port.
I am using webfaction to host my app and I am able to change and access the web admin url as mydomain/neo4j (point to mydomain:port). But the query cannot work in webadmin.